# Send several POSTs using Data Body from random files

Tags: post, jmeter

JMeter scenario:

*The purpose:* I need to send a POST HTTP Requests (several requests at the same time for performance verification, each one is with separate thread) using the contents of random files from the selected folder.

```
Steps: 

    a. read all Data at once from random file
    b. insert Data to Body Data of HTTP Request (format of body is bellow)
    c. send HTTP Request with separate thread

Protocol: https
Server: app1
HTTP Request: POST
Path: Web/TestResultsServices.asmx/GetTestResults
```

File(s) format is *.txt*, if necessary, can be converted into *.csv*
*Content:* (15 up 500 lines)

[image: Body Data]

Single Body Data POST:  (Request for 10 lines)

[image: Single POST]

I tried to use

1. StringFromFile:
   Result: Read first line only

[image: StringFromFile]

2. FileToString:
   Result: All lines of file

[image: FileToString]

Question: How to use it value in specified thread, send POST with read Data and jumpt to next file (and next  thread)

Answer (score 0):

- "several requests at the same time" - [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)
- "using the contents of random files from the selected folder" - [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager))
- " read all Data at once from random file" - [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)